# How to set spark.executor.extraClassPath & spark.driver.extraClassPath in hive query without adding those in hive-site.xml

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

I Have a hql file which is being used in oozie hive action. I am running hive on spark engine by specifying the below in my hql file.

`set hive.execution.engine=spark;`

But the job is failing with error :
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/tree/CommonTree`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTree`

I researched about it and trying to solve this by setting `spark.executor.extraClassPath` & `spark.driver.extraClassPath`

I found this can be done by adding the entry in hive-site.xml . But I am trying to set this on run time by adding the below command in my hql file like below :

set spark.executor.extraClassPath=/abc/external_jars/antlr-runtime-4.7.jar;
set spark.driver.extraClassPath=/abc/external_jars/antlr-runtime-4.7.jar;

But how can I add multiple jar file like this or is this the correct way to set the Classpath in runtime via hive ?

Thanks

Tried to run hive query via oozie action by setting the engine as spark. But it is failing
with Exception : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/tree/CommonTree`

Expecting to run the job successfully by correctly identifying the antlr jar file.

Thanks

Comment: Can you set those in the spark-env.sh ? Wouldn't you want all Spark code to have access to that library, not just specific Hive queries?

Comment: Basically I am trying to set this at job level only for this hive query which is using hive as its executing engine.